# SQL query for Informix to get all the records from previous month

Tags: sql, informix

I need a query which can generate the total no of records generated in the previous month.
I started with this query:

```
select state, taxing_entity, count(taxing_entity) Total_TRXN_Count
from taxes where effect_date between '2016/07/01' and '2016/07/31' 
group by state, taxing_entity, effect_date
```

But I need a query which can dynamically calculate the no of records for a previous month without hard coding the dates. I tried many queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM taxes 
WHERE effect_date >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate()) 
and effect_date <= getdate()
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM taxes
WHERE effect_date >= DATEADD(effect_date, -1, GETDATE())
```

but I have had no success until now. Can someone please suggest a way to get the total records from a previous month using the Informix dialect of SQL?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm using Informix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Background

You can do it with Informix functions `TODAY`, `MONTH()`, `YEAR()` and `MDY()` — and a little jiggery-pokery.

The expression for the first day of this month is:

```
MDY(MONTH(TODAY), 1, YEAR(TODAY))
```

The expression for the first day of the prior month, therefore, is:

```
MDY(MONTH(TODAY), 1, YEAR(TODAY)) - 1 UNITS MONTH
```

The advantage of these expressions is that they are unambiguous and reliable; they don't depend on anything special (in the SQL you write) to find the last day of the month.  You can find the last day of the month by subtracting `1 UNITS DAY` from the first day of the following month.  With modern versions of Informix, you can do date arithmetic that rounds to the end of month:

```
SELECT MDY(1,31,2016) + 1 UNITS MONTH FROM sysmaster:'informix'.sysdual;
2016-02-29
```

but older versions of Informix would generate an error instead.  Even now, `MDY(2,31,2016)` generates an 'invalid day in month' error.

### Answer

So for the problem in the question, the date range you want is:

```
SELECT *
  FROM taxes
 WHERE effect_date >= (MDY(MONTH(TODAY), 1, YEAR(TODAY)) - 1 UNITS MONTH)
   AND effect_date <   MDY(MONTH(TODAY), 1, YEAR(TODAY))
```

It is easier to use 'before the first day of this month' than to use 'on or before the last day of the previous month'.  However you could write:

```
SELECT *
  FROM taxes
 WHERE effect_date >= (MDY(MONTH(TODAY), 1, YEAR(TODAY)) - 1 UNITS MONTH)
   AND effect_date <= (MDY(MONTH(TODAY), 1, YEAR(TODAY)) - 1 UNITS DAY)
```

or, equivalently:

```
SELECT *
  FROM taxes
 WHERE effect_date BETWEEN (MDY(MONTH(TODAY), 1, YEAR(TODAY)) - 1 UNITS MONTH)
                       AND (MDY(MONTH(TODAY), 1, YEAR(TODAY)) - 1 UNITS DAY)
```

#### Using stored procedures

You could generalize the code by using any chosen date in place of `TODAY`, and you could write one or two simple stored procedures to do those calculations if you think they're too obscure as shown.  Possible names would include `first_day_this_month` and `first_day_prev_month`, passing the reference date as an argument, defaulting to TODAY:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE first_day_this_month(refdate DATE DEFAULT TODAY)
    RETURNING DATE AS first_day;
    RETURN MDY(MONTH(refdate), 1, YEAR(refdate));
END PROCEDURE;

CREATE PROCEDURE first_day_prev_month(refdate DATE DEFAULT TODAY)
    RETURNING DATE AS first_day;
    RETURN MDY(MONTH(refdate), 1, YEAR(refdate)) - 1 UNITS MONTH;
END PROCEDURE;
```

Example use (assuming you have DBDATE='Y4MD-' or equivalent in your environment, so DATE strings look like ISO 8601 or DATETIME strings):

```
SELECT first_day_this_month() AS aug_1,
       first_day_prev_month() AS jul_1,
       first_day_this_month(DATE('2015-12-25')) as dec_1,
       first_day_prev_month(DATE('2015-10-31')) AS sep_1
  FROM sysmaster:'informix'.sysdual;
```

Output:

```
aug_1        jul_1        dec_1        sep_1
2016-08-01   2016-07-01   2015-12-01   2015-09-01
```

And hence:

```
SELECT *
  FROM taxes
 WHERE effect_date >= first_day_prev_month()
   AND effect_date <  first_day_this_month()
```

Answer (score 3):

A few years old but I assume this is still relevant info:

```
effect_date >=
    MDY(month(current - 1 units month), 1, year(current - 1 units month))
and effect_date < 
    MDY(month(current), 1, year(current))
```

http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1627297-Informix-query-to-find-first-date-of-previous-month

Of course if you were given a random date and you need to cover it's month from the first to the end, the pattern is similar:

```
effect_date >=
    MDY(month(<given_date>), 1, year(<given_date>))
and effect_date <
    MDY(month(<given_date> + 1 units month), 1, year(<given_date> + 1 units month))
```

Comment: Except that I'd use TODAY instead of CURRENT, ...the same answer that I suggested at just about the same time as you.  (The created date on my answer is misleading; I accidentally submitted about 2 lines of text as answer, so I deleted it and edited it in the deleted state.)

Comment: @Jonathan Whew! I only saw yours after hitting submit but I was pretty sure it hadn't been there before. I don't know any Informix so you'll have to inform me why that's better.

Comment: CURRENT is an abbreviation for CURRENT YEAR TO FRACTION(3), so it generates a DATETIME value rather than a DATE, which is then converted to DATE.  The internal representations are quite different; DATE is an integer type with day 1 being 1900-01-01, but DATETIME is based on a DECIMAL type.  They're readily inter-convertible, but there's marginally more work involved with CURRENT than TODAY.  But I brushed over that because the `- 1 UNITS MONTH` notation uses DATETIME (and INTERVAL) types, so there's conversions between DATE and DATETIME and back to DATE in the code I used too.

Comment: In Informix, `TODAY - 1` is yesterday, which is useful but not necessarily immediately obvious.  All systems get rather verbose when manipulating dates — witness the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in MSSQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM taxes
WHERE effect_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, effect_date)
```

I'm not too familiar with Informix, but the syntax shouldn't be too far off.

Comment: this isn't valid in mssq or any rdbms that I am aware ofl!  DATEADD() doesn't accept 2 dates as parameters

Comment: The above example uses 3 parameters: effect_date, -1, and GETDATE() for the current date.

Comment: wow yes it used 3 parameters but not it is NOT valid!  read the documentation.  The first paramter is a datepart such as day, month, year, the second the interval and the 3rd the date you want to modify.  effect_date is a column of datetime datatype it is NOT a datepart.  This is very far from being valid and this answer should be deleted!

Comment: I edited the answer - now it is valid. I just had it mixed up. effect_date is the date he is looking to compare with.

Comment: Yes it is now a valid statement, but not one that works for any situation I am aware of because it will always be true, effect_date will always be >= to itself 1 month ago.  GETDATE() would be proper if he wanted everything from the equivalent day last month.  But seeing it is August he is requesting everything from July for example.

Answer (score 0):

well I had this prepared because sql-server was tagged you can translate the it to informix maybe I will look it up too.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    taxes
WHERE
    effect_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())),MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())),1)
    AND effect_date < DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),1)
```

I think infomix might just be:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    taxes
WHERE
    effect_date >= MDY(MONTH(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT,-1)),1,YEAR(ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT,-1)))
    AND effect_date < MDY(MONTH(CURRENT),1,YEAR(CURRENT))
```

If you change from <= to < then you really don't have to search by end of last month but rather than beginning of this month.  Which if you effect_date has time included would actually be what you want because of the midnight issue.