# query to generate transactions from previous month

Tags: sql, informix

I need to write a query which when executed at the beginning of the current month must generate a report which contains total transactions made in the previous month and I have written the below query:

```
SELECT 
l.state AS Province 
,l.taxing_entity AS TaxJurisdiction 
,COUNT(DISTINCT t.trans_id) AS TotalTransCount 
FROM TRANSACTION AS t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN location AS l 
ON t.location_id = l.location_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_line AS tl 
ON t.trans_id = tl.trans_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contract as c 
ON t.contract_id = c.contract_id 
WHERE 
l.chain_id = 10 
AND c.issuer_id IN (156967) 
AND t.extra_5 BETWEEN LAST_DAY(TODAY - 2 units month) + 1 units day AND  LAST_DAY(TODAY - 1 units month) 
AND tl.cat NOT IN ('DEF','DEFD','DEFC')
GROUP BY l.state, l.taxing_entity, Province 
ORDER BY l.state,l.taxing_entity
```

But this query throws an error `"It is not possible to convert between the specified types. "`. I tried changing the date range as below:

```
t.extra_5 >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 31, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0) AND t.extra_5 < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
```

and

```
t.extra_5 > DateAdd(WEEK, -1, GETDATE()+1) and t.extra_5<=GETDATE()
```

But nothing has worked out so far. The current format for the column `"extra_5"` is as below:

[image]

Can someone please suggest a way to get the total transactions from previous month.

Comment: You probably need to cast `extra_5`. Not sure of the Informix types but likely something along the lines of `cast(extra_5 as date)`.

Comment: A good first step to handling dates sanely is storing dates as DATE or DATETIME YEAR TO DAY or something similar.  I run with `DBDATE=Y4MD-` set in my environment; that's effectively the same format as DATETIME types use.  With that set, I could use: `create temp table td9(ds char(8) not null);`, `insert into td9 values('20131120');`, and `select date(ds) from td9;` to retrieve the date value `2013-11-20`.  However, changing `DBDATE=MDY4/` stops the same query working ('invalid month in date' — reasonable; there isn't a month 20).

Comment: See also the recent SO question [SQL query for Informix to get all the records from previous month?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003297)  It covers your concerns somewhat differently.  `LAST_DAY()` is interesting; I'd not come across it before (but it seems to work, giving the last day of the month referenced in the argument).  Sadly, there doesn't seem to be the analogous `FIRST_DAY()` function.